# $payment->getCcNumber()?

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, payment, ee-1.12, payment-methods

`$payment` is of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment` which extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Info` which in turn extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

On EE 1.12, there is no column `cc_number` (`cc_number_enc` exists) in `sales_flat_order_payment` and I don't see any function defined `getCcNumner()`, either. There's an extension that calls `payment->getCcNumber()`, and it's returning null. I do see other core codes that call this function as well..

Am I missing something here, or is this `getCcNumber()` not valid?

Comment: It's likely referring to a magic method that will return data if `setCcNumber()` was called previously. `getData('cc_number')` is effectively the same thing.

Comment: But don't magic methods only work if the corresponding columns are in the model's table? In this case, a column named `cc_number`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: No, it works when `$this->setCcNumber($ccnumber)` or `$this->setData('cc_number', $value)` was called. Maybe the backend model of the cc_number handles it or the cc_number has his own `attribute_model` which does this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the class `Mage_Payment_Model_Info` which deals with the information of the payment. There is a custom getData function. This will take the stored encoded cc_number field and decrypt it so that the user can call `getCcNumber()`

```
public function getData($key='', $index=null)
{
    if ('cc_number'===$key) {
        if (empty($this->_data['cc_number']) && !empty($this->_data['cc_number_enc'])) {
            $this->_data['cc_number'] = $this->decrypt($this->getCcNumberEnc());
        }
    }
    if ('cc_cid'===$key) {
        if (empty($this->_data['cc_cid']) && !empty($this->_data['cc_cid_enc'])) {
            $this->_data['cc_cid'] = $this->decrypt($this->getCcCidEnc());
        }
    }
    return parent::getData($key, $index);
}
```

When it is being saved there is the revers of this and the encrypt. This is done under the `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` in the function `prepareSave()`

```
public function prepareSave()
{
    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();
    if ($this->_canSaveCc) {
        $info->setCcNumberEnc($info->encrypt($info->getCcNumber()));
    }
    //$info->setCcCidEnc($info->encrypt($info->getCcCid()));
    $info->setCcNumber(null)
        ->setCcCid(null);
    return $this;
}
```